# Patrones en Entity de Watson Assistant

Tags: regex, ibm-bluemix

Estoy intentando hacer un regex para una Entity de Watson Assistant que me detecte las fechas similares a las que están en negrita:

- fecha 25/2/2020 30/2/2020
- fecha /25/2 **30/2** de
- fecha **18/02** de
- fecha 12/12/ de
- fecha 12/12/
- fecha **12/12**

He utilizado la siguiente expresión para realizarlo:

```
(\b(?:3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])([\-/.])(1[1-2]|0?[1-9])(?![\-/.])\b)
```

Esta expresión funciona bien, el problema es que el motor de comparación de patrones que se utiliza, tiene limitaciones de sintaxis. (https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-entities)

- Los patrones de entidad no pueden contener:

  - Repeticiones positivas (por ejemplo, x*+)
  - Referencias anteriores (por ejemplo, \g1)
  - Ramas condicionales (por ejemplo, (?(cond)true))

En este punto, no puedo utilizar `(?![\-/.])` para que no se seleccione fechas como 25/2/2020, ya que contiene la '/'.

Habría alguna solución?

Gracias de antemano,

Comment: Creo que podrías usar esos simbolos sí los escapas utilizando un backslash "\" por ejemplo: \/ para / o \. para .

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Por suerte, la detección de fechas de Watson Assistant  ha sido actualizada y ya detecta fechas como 12/12. Saludos